# Frobenius method giving me a wrong value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

So I have this problem and it's making me crazy, I'm pretty sure it's simple but I'm getting stuck at a certain part.

$$x^2y''+xy'+2xy = 0$$ at x = 0.

So, x = 0 is a singular point (also regular, already did the math), so we need to use the Frobenius method to solve this.

I got:

$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } A_{n} x^{r + n}$$

$$y' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n-1}$$

$$y'' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n-1)(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n-2}$$

Putting the terms on the equation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n-1)(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } 2A_{n} x^{r + n + 1}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n-1)(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } 2A_{n-1} x^{r + n}$$

And finally:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n-1)(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(r+n)}A_{n} x^{r + n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } 2A_{n-1} x^{r + n}$$

From this we get the indicial equation:

$$((r-1)(r)+r) = 0$$

Giving me $r=0$. Don't really think this is possible for singular points.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think that this is not possible for a singular point?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you a-priori reject the case $r=0$ ?

Case $r=0$ :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } n^2 A_{n} x^{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } 2A_{n-1} x^{n}=0$$
$$A_n=-\frac{2}{n^2}A_{n-1} \quad\to\quad A_n=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n}{(n!)^2}A_0 \qquad \qquad n\geq 1$$
$$y(x)=A_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n 2^n}{(n!)^2}x^n =c_1 J_0(2\sqrt{2x}) \qquad\qquad \text{Bessel function of first kind}.$$
where $c_1=A_0=$ any constant.

Of course, this method makes to loose the solutions which are not expandable in series of the form assumed $y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } A_{n} x^{r + n}$ , especially those which are singular at $x=0$ . This is the case of the solutions of the form :
$$y=c_2Y_0(2\sqrt{2x})\qquad\qquad \text{Bessel function of second kind}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Compare coefficients of $x^{n+r+1}$ to obtain a recurrence relation in $a_n$. Find $a_1$,$a_2$,... and plug them in your Frobenius series  $y=x^r(a_0+a_1x+a_2+....)$. The complete solution is given by $y=(A+Blogx).y_1$ where $y_1=(y)_{r=0}$.