# Using Cauchy-Euler method to solve $x^2 y''+2xy'-xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ODE
$$x^2 y''+2xy'-xy=0$$
I have to solve it using Cauchy-Euler's method. Writing
$$y=x^n$$
then
$$y'=n x^{n-1},\quad y''=n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
and therefore
$$x^{2}\cdot n(n-1)x^{n-2}+2x nx^{n-1}-x\cdot x^n=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^{n}(n^2+n-x)=0$$
which gives the equaiton
$$n^2+n-x=0$$
Solving the equation above, should the solution be
$$y(x)=x^{n}$$
where $n=\displaystyle\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$?

Comment: You treated $n$ as a constant at the beginning.

Comment: @VIVID but isn't this way? I mean, to arrive in a equation of $n$?

Comment: No, the issue is if n is a function of x then the power rule doesn't apply, so your form for y' doesn't work.

Comment: @mvfs314 Your equation is not in the form of the second order Cauchy–Euler equation yet. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation#Second_order_%E2%80%93_solving_through_trial_solution

Comment: @VIVID that's what I thought. Is it possible to turn into the right form to solve it?

Comment: Then some clever substitution needed but I don't see how. This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036802/frobenius-method-giving-me-a-wrong-value?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify by $x$ and rewrite the equation as$$x y''(x)+2 y'(x)=y(x)\tag{1}$$
set
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
so we have
$$y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$
and
$$y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$
Substitute in $(1)$
$$x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
and finally
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
set equal the coefficients of the powers of $x$ in both sides
$$
\begin{cases}
2a_1=a_0,& a_1=\frac{1}{2}a_0\\
6a_2=a_1,& a_2=\frac{1}{12}a_0\\
12a_3=a_2,& a_3=\frac{1}{144}a_0\\
20a_4=a_3,& a_4=\frac{1}{2880}a_1\\
30a_5=a_4,& a_5=\frac{1}{86400}a_1\\
\ldots\\
a_n=\frac{1}{n!(n+1)!}
\end{cases}
$$
So the solution is, suppose $y(0)=y'(0)=1$,
$$y(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n! (n+1)!}$$
$$y(x)=\frac{I_1\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
where $I_1(t)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: I do appreciate it but is this the Cauchy-Euler's method?

Comment: @mvfs314 No, your equation is not a Cauchy-Euler equation, that's why the method does not work. My solution is based on Frobenius method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method